# Implementing CNN from scratch with numpy only and save model

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Currently, I am learning CNN by myself. I find lots of sources on the Internet. But most of them use Pytorch and Tensorflow. I want to find some examples for image classification that uses NumPy only and have some way to train my dataset, save and load the trained model. Does anyone know where is the example?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library if you are interested: https://github.com/samrere/pytortto
basically it's a pytorch written in numpy&cupy. It completely follows pytorch interface, and can be trained in GPU.
I've included several basic examples, such as training Resnet, UNet, vision transformer and DCGAN, all trained/finetuned entirely using simple numpy functions.